# What are the effects of using Ifeature.Delete() on a feature within a feature class?

Tags: arcobjects, feature-class

I call Delete() on a feature in a feature class, then I want to proceed to the next feature by using ICursor.NextRow() but this produces an error. The code is simple:
EDIT: More code showing the instantiation of the cursor and the version is ArcGIS 10.2

```
 ICursor curs;
 object id;
 IFeature feature;
 curs = (ICursor)fclass.Search(new QueryFilter(), true);
 feature = (IFeature)curs.NextRow();
 if(some_criteria){

 while (feature != null)
        {
            try
            {

                id = feature.get_Value(index); //get the ID of the record which is not in source
                if (id does not exist in target)
                {
                    feature.Delete();
                }
                feature = (IFeature)curs.NextRow();
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);//testing purposes
            }
        }
        curs = null;
    }
}
```

Now, the deletion occurs, but in the next iteration, I get an error at the line: id=feature.get_Value(index) saying "Feature was deleted". My question is, shouldn't reassigning feature to the next row be good enough to move on?

Comment: How about a larger chunk of code, so we can see how all the objects were instantiated?  It would also help to specify the version of ArcGIS in use.

Comment: It sounds like you're using a recycling cursor, can you include the part about the creation of the cursor. Note: *curs = null;* is not the way to get rid of the cursor object use ReleaseComObject to close the cursor and remove locks.

Answer (score 7):

The method for removing a feature depends on the cursor.

If you are using a recycling cursor: `pCur = pFeatClass.Search(null,true)` do not call delete in any way, shape or form. Calling delete on a recycling cursor removes the buffer so there is nothing to load the next feature into which is why it's getting cranky when you call `NextFeature()` - you've already broken the buffer!

In order to delete a feature on a [search cursor](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//0025000002t9000000):

```
IFeatureCursor pCur = pFeatClass.Search(pQF,false); // not recycling
IFeature pFeat = pCur.NextFeature();
do
{
  pFeat.Delete();
  pFeat = pCur.NextFeature();
} while (pFeat != null);
```

To delete a feature on an [update cursor](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#/Update_Method/0025000002tq000000/):

```
IFeatureCursor pCur = pFeatClass.Update(pQF,false); // not recycling
IFeature pFeat = pCur.NextFeature();
do
{ 
  pCur.DeleteFeature(); // not called on the feature directly
  pFeat = pCur.NextFeature();
} while (pFeat != null);
```

To dismiss the cursor use [ReleaseComObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.releasecomobject%28v=vs.71%29.aspx):

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(pCur);
```

If you want to delete a few features using a query filter then use the [ITable interface](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//00250000089m000000):

```
ITable pTable = (ITable) pFeatClass; // ITable inherits from IFeatureClass
pTable.DeleteSearchedRows(pQF); // delete every row that fits the query filter
```

This is a much safer way to remove a lot of features that satisfy the query. Note: if the [query filter](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/IQueryFilter_Interface/0025000006mr000000/) is null then it will remove ALL ROWS (features). I'm not sure if it would work if you used a [spatial filter](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/ISpatialFilter_Interface/00250000083n000000/) on an ITable object but I wouldn't try it!